# Toggle region in Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

In Bootstrap, How to make a link (button) which toggles a region.

My intention is to Show/Hide  debug information kept in a `<div>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is nothing to do with bootstrap; it's basic JavaScript.

Add  an ID to the link, and to the `<div />` you want to toggle, and then use the jQuery [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle) method (as jQuery is included with bootstrap).

```
$('#your_link_id').on('click', function () {
    $('#your_div_id').toggle();
});
```

You can even use [`slideToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle) instead of `toggle()` if you wanted a cool sliding effect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the bootstrap collapse plugin. More info [here](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#collapse).

All it needs is reference to `Bootstrap.js` and `bootstrap.css`